# Hex file formatting

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

The syntax highlighting of hex files is bad, as shown in [What PIC processor was this HEX-file meant for?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/62112/17592):

[image]

Can something be done about that?

Comment: Badly formatted how? Do you mean the syntax highligting?

Comment: @trygvis yes, sorry for not being clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the tags you use, different code syntax highlighting will be used. You selected the [assembly](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assembly) tag, which has a code syntax style default. It's not exactly assembly because there isn't a code format for that available.

I wouldn't expect a "proper" syntax highlighting for your code as that is more of a file format (Intel Hex) rather than a code language (C, ASM, Python, etc...). The syntax highlighting is done using Google Prettify (see [editing help](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) for more info).

Comment: It would be nice to have a syntax highlighting for Intel Hex files, since the format itself is so hard to read.  At least get the addresses and checksums in different colors.  I see prettyify takes plugins...

Comment: [Here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63800/interface-options-for-specifying-language-prettify/81970#81970) is a list with interface options for specifying a language using prettify. `lang-none` is appropriate in this case.